# Make multiple ajax using Jquery in a sequence

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working with a very poorly done endpoint...So please understand that I won't be able change how this endpoint behaves.

This ajax call is: POST /doStupidThing/.

Given a list of ids, I need to call the endpoint for each id.
How can I make sure the call doesn't get fired before the previous call completes ? Should I just set async to false ?

Comment: Why would you want to disable async processing in this case, have a larger number of calls is exactly where you would want to take advantage of async processing. If number is too large, I can understand you might need to limit number of concurrent connections, but seems backwards to me.

Comment: The backend code is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try setting async to false

Answer (score 0):

[Just for the record, the better way to do things would be to set yourself up to use the Jquery promise interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080050/how-does-jquerys-promise-method-really-work)

[This SO answer covers this in more detail and talks about deferred objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486934/how-to-call-second-jquery-ajax-instance-on-success-of-first-and-update-page)

One thing you can do is make your next ajax call in your .done function.

```
function SecondAjax() { 
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.php",
      data: data_obj,
      dataType: "html"
   }).done(function(msg) {
         #You can put a third one in here
         #This should also give you an idea of how to loop.
      }
}

function firstAjax() { 
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.php",
      data: data_obj,
      dataType: "html"
   }).done(function(msg) {
         SecondAjax()
      }
}
```